# Which member of the fellowship made the most onscreen kills?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, movie, tolkiens-legendarium, kill-count

Of the nine members of the fellowship, who had the highest onscreen kills?

Rules:

- Only the three LotR trilogy films *count*
- Any individual creature counts as 1 (eg. when Legolas kills enemies on top of and including the oliphant, each of those are individually counted)
- Accidental deaths **do not** count (eg. in the extended RotK, Gimli 'bumps' Legolas' bow to slay Peter Jackson)
- The Helm's Deep contest is ignored
- The member has to have **personally** killed the enemy, not getting others to do it for the member himself.

Comment: Probably Legolas but I don't know.

Comment: @Bellerephon, i would guess one of the three hunters myself.

Comment: Legolas was one of the hunters and he killed about 8 people on that oliphant.

Comment: Nah, surely it would be Pippin. Must have incinerated a couple hundred woodlice when he lit the signal fire... and that was totally on purpose. (Not in the book of course.)

Comment: Aragorn arranged for the murder of an entire army of orcs using his ghost-slaves. Does that count?

Comment: Gandalf personally arranged the destruction of the entire Orc race.

Comment: @Valorum, i will edit the question to say which member _personally_ made the kill, not getting others to do it for them.

Comment: What about Frodo and the Ring killing thousands of Orcs?

Comment: @user35594 - Gandalf is basically a god.I'm not entirely sure there's much difference between him hitting someone with a stick and him getting someone to hit someone with a stick.

Comment: @Valorum, Gandalf certainly didn't seem all that powerful in the movies (not sure about the novels).

Comment: @user35594 - Do you get more HP for a boss battle?

Comment: Gandalf is extremely powerful but is banned by gods from using his full power except against other gods like the Balrog.

Comment: @Valorum, i think MP would have been more useful considering the lack of spells used.

Comment: According to Gimli, the Oliphant and crew should only count as one.

Comment: @Mattson Gimli cheats. Although he wins the contest due to off-screen kills in the book.

Comment: This makes me want to go through and watch them all and keep track. You monster. That'd be a day of time gone!

Comment: @enderland, a good day of time i hope!

Comment: This reminds me of the scene where Gimli and Legolas are comparing the number of kills they've made!

Comment: Well, Aragorn caused the Dead Men of Dunharrow to fulfil their oaths, thereby moving from 'undead' to 'full dead'. So like, if that's counted, then he's the "Death King". BAM!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that the death was on screen and clear (ie not from being knocked down):

```
Character FoTR   TT RotK Total
Aragorn     23    3    1  27+?
Legolas     20    8    1  29+?
Gimli        6    3    0   9+?
```

These breakdowns for FoTR and TT are detailed.

Currently lacking a detailed breakdown for Return of the King. Using the above numbers for the first two movies (note that most of the fellowship kills in Two Towers are at Helms Deep, which you are ignoring) my assumption would be Legolas given the lead he has after the first two movies. Much more of the combat scenes in RoTK follow him than Aragorn.

Sources:

- [The Fellowship of the Ring](http://moviebodycounts.proboards.com/thread/444/lotr-fellowship-ring-extended-version)
- [The Two Towers](http://moviebodycounts.proboards.com/thread/439/lotr-towers-extended-version)
- [The Return of the King](http://moviebodycounts.proboards.com/thread/483/return-king-extended-edition)

Comment: If people find a better breakdown for RotK I can [edit] to include that information.

Comment: Since the bulk of the kill comes from FoTR, Boromir can contest with them. He killed as much as Legolas and Aragon in Moria and maybe more before he died.

Comment: @C.Koca Boromir only killed 17 on screen in Fellowship.

Comment: Is this extended or theatre cut?

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain but I think it was Legolas. It was none of the hobbits. Frodo killed practically no one. Sam killed a few including Shelob but no where near as many as the rest of the Fellowship. Merry and Pippin both killed a few in the last 2 films but not as many as the fighting members. Gandalf missed half a film and since he rarely fights low level enemies he doesn't rack up a high kill count. Boromoir got the most kills in the first film but the others overtook after he died. This leaves the three main fighters. Gimli kills a lot but loses the counting contest and is unlikely to have caught up at other times. Aragon killed a lot of enemies but Legolas I think killed roughly the same during battles and overtakes by occasionally sniping enemies at a distance.

Comment: Sam didn't kill Shelob (at least, death wasn't on-screen, and in the book she didn't die)

Comment: @DavidRoberts The book leaves it open: "Shelob was gone; and whether she lay long in her lair [recovering], this tale does not tell".

Answer (score 1):

**Frodo.** Gollum was pushed by Frodo. We do not perfectly know if it was his intention to push him or he just wanted to take the ring back. If it was intentional he killed way more than anyone else.

**Legolas, if Frodo caused Gollum to fall by accident.** I do not know what *Helm's Deep contest is ignored* means. If it means we shouldn't take Legolas claiming he killed 17 without being shown or if it means that we should not directly take the 43-42 score in the book, Legolas killed about 50 or more by making the ladder fall in Helm's Deep. Aragon kicked a ladder as well, but there was only one orc on top of it.

Answer (score -1):

Legolas is the only logical answer. By *Two Towers* he was at seventeen already, while Gimli is only at two by then. The ladder, the shield-surf, Legolas is always in action, shooting arrows while retreating, he's got his two elvish blades and a sword and uses all of his weaponry and even is riding out in the end when Gimli is blowing the Horn.

The numbers in the book make no sense and for what we see in the movie, these numbers also don't make sense. Way too small in general and Gimli definitely didn't catch up to Legolas to win by just one. Just doesn't make sense for what we see. I don't know the exact final tallies, but 113 for Legolas and 87 for Gimli or something like that would be more plausible.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Did you note in the question that the contest at Helm's Deep wasn't part of the count?  You should redo your count without that, and provide details of how you are counting.  (Only onscreen counts, so if Legolas fires an arrow offscreen then it doesn't count.)

Answer (score -3):

Gollum did. When he fell into the fires of Mount Doom with the ring legions of the enemy were decimated. The OP said accidents don't count however was this an accident?  Gandalf knew from the beginning that Gollum had a role to play, he just didn't know what it was. Now he knows.

Comment: Golumn was not a member of the fellowship. The Fellowship is Aragorn, Legolas, Gimli, Borormir, Gandalf, Frodo, Sam, Merry and Pippin.

Comment: If we're just gonna count random non-Fellowship characters, I nominate Eru.

Comment: Gollum was not picked randomly, he was acting as guide to a portion of the fellowship. He may not have been am ideal companion but he did provide a needed service to the fellowship and Frodo took him willingly as a companion.

Comment: @Valorum Illuvator killed more than Eru.

Comment: @Bellerephon - Morgoth?

Comment: @Bellerophon Isn't Gollum a member of the fellowship? Maybe Frodo would disagree in certain moments.

Comment: @TGar In the question it specifically states the 9 members of the Fellowship. Gollum may have been a member of Sam, Frodo and Gollum's trio but he was not a part of the original 9 who made up the fellowship.

Comment: @Bellerophon I didn't notice the number, you're right of course (it should be partially a joke from me, but it doesn't work).

Comment: @Bellerophon But I now see your previous comment and I don't get it... I always thought that Eru and Illuvatar are the same characters...

Comment: @TGar Yes, you're right. Not sure why I posted that comment.